# cocos2d-x setDesignResolution TmxTileMap scrolling flickering

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

When I scroll a cocos2d::TMXTiledMap in native resolution everything is fine but when the whole scene is resized by using setDesignResolution the cocos2d::TMXTiledMap is flickering when scrolled.

This is also the case, when I only scroll by even positions.

For me it looks like, there is a transformation / translation issue.

The tmx tile map is scrolled fine, when I move the map considering the scale factor.

For example: DesignResolution is 960x720, ScreenSize is 1000x750

```
_posX -= 1.0f * 720.0f / 750.0f;
_map->setPositionX(_posX);
```

But, if I do this, the map does not move with correct speed, because it is not moved anymore by 1.0 units on the x axis.

Somebody has a hint how to correct this wrong projection?

Thank you!

Comment: why libgdx tag ?

Comment: During my internet search, I mostly found similar discussions about this issue which also happens with libgdx. I know that this is not related to libgdx but maybe someone has a theoretical background for this issue.